# perl thread dies after detach

Tags: multithreading, perl, asynchronous

I need to create a thread and let it do some stuff. The main reason is to quit from main programm as fast as possible.
But after I detach the thread and end the main programm, the thread dies. In my example the file doesn´t contain expected data.
If I let the main programm sleep for 5 sec everything works fine.

How can I let run the thread after quitting from the main prog?

```
use threads;
print "Starting main program\n";
my $t = threads->new(\&sub1)->detach();
print "End of main program\n";

sub sub1 {
        print "started thread\n";

        open (FILE, ">>./test.txt") or die($!);
        print FILE localtime(time())."\n";
        foreach (1..3){
          print FILE "$_\n";
          sleep 1;
        }
        close(FILE);
         return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, you can't.

> - [**$thr->detach()**](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#%24thr-%3Edetach%28%29)
>     Makes the thread unjoinable, and causes any eventual return value to be discarded. When the program *exits*, any detached threads that are still running are silently *terminated*.

But you could do:

```
threads->new(\&sub1)->join();
```

But that hardly buys you much. Because threads are mainly meant to be used to do other things while you continue to do some thing. There is little reason to stop the main line of execution, and then run a thread, when you could just as well have called `sub1();`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I think in my case I have to use something ilke system("prg_name.pl &").

Answer (score 1):

You can't use threads, but you could fork and let parent process exit without waiting for the child process to finish:

```
my $pid = fork();
if ($pid == 0) {
  print "child proc\n";
  sleep 5;
  print "child, 5 seconds older\n";
  exit(0);
} else {
  print "parent proc. goodbye\n";
}
```

I don't think this isn't a very good approach since you've now lost control over the child process. Why not just run it main and background the process?

**Edit**: This of course also has the potential to generate zombie processes, which will consume system resources. and brains.

Comment: I don't want to produce zombies:-). I just tryed to background process with system("prg_name.pl &"). And it works, but is a little bit scruffy solution in my case.